# Create constant outside of method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method test in a concern as below

```
module company
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    def test(emp)
      employees = { '0' => 'A', '1' => 'B'}.freeze
      employees[emp]
    end
  end
end
```

This method will create a hash every time it is called. How can I declare a hash outside as a constant? 
I tried to create a local variable of a hash and call it in a method, but am not sure if that fixes the hash creation every time the method is called.

Comment: Yes, you can [create a constant](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Constants) outside of the method. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: how can i create constant variable outside method?

Comment: Follow the link in my comment. Quote: "A variable whose name begins with an uppercase letter (A-Z) is a constant."

Comment: I'd probably extract `employees` into a method and memoize the value in an instance variable, i.e. `def employees; @employees ||= { ... }.freeze; end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module Company
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  EMPLOYEES = { '0' => 'A', '1' => 'B'}.freeze

  included do
    def test(emp)
      EMPLOYEES[emp]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: so employees is a local variable right? so its a constant too?

Comment: @User4432432432 `EMPLOYEES` is a constant. In Ruby constant is a variable written with caps

Comment: a variable *starting* with a capital